# How can i return a loop?

Tags: swiftui

I want to know the scrollview offset and found in the internet that they did this in this way:

```
GeometryReader { geometry -> Text in
                        let newOffset = geometry.frame(in: .global).minY
                        if newOffset != self.offset {
                            self.offset = newOffset
                        }
                        return 
                            Text("aha")
                    }
```

unfortunately my "return-type" is

```
ForEach (MathTaskType.allCases) { eachType in
                                MathTypeRow(mathType: eachType)
                            }
```

and i have no idea what to write here (xxxx).

i tried it with Group around it, but i didn't get this to run...

Thank you for your help.

```
 GeometryReader { geometry -> xxxxxx in  //  what do i have to input here?
                    let newOffset = geometry.frame(in: .global).minY
                    if newOffset != self.offset {
                        self.offset = newOffset
                    }
                    return 
                        ForEach (MathTaskType.allCases) { eachType in
                            MathTypeRow(mathType: eachType)
                        }

                }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, the AnyView type is the rescue:

```
GeometryReader { geometry -> AnyView in
                    let newOffset = geometry.frame(in: .global).minY
                    if newOffset != self.offset {
                        self.offset = newOffset
                    }
                    return AnyView ( // <- Here!
                        ForEach (MathTaskType.allCases) { eachType in
                            MathTypeRow(mathType: eachType)
                        }
                    )
                }
```

It converts any View to a universal type, without difficulties with generic types.

Of course, the ForEach also has a type from itself, I guess it's something like `ForEach<[MathTaskType], MathTaskType.ID, MathTypeRow>`. But that's not more beautiful, working with AnyView also gives flexibility for future changes.

Answer (score 0):

```
   return GeometryReader { geometry in

        List(someData, id: \.self) { data in
            Text("\(data)")


        Text("x: \(geometry.frame(in: .global).origin.x)")
        Text("y: \(geometry.frame(in: .global).origin.y)")
    }
}
```

This would display the global (x,y coordinates inside your current view) for your reference.

Comment: sorry James, i know how to do that, and this was not the question....